# ffmpeg change the order of the output

Tags: linux, audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming

i try to change the order of the output of 3 inputs (2 audio + 1 video)
this is my command:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -async 1 \
-f pulse -i alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor \
-f pulse -i alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo \
-f x11grab -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 8 -i :0.0 \
-filter_complex amix=inputs=2 \
-c:a aac -b:a 128k \
-c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 1500k -maxrate 1500k -minrate 1500k \
-override_ffserver -g 16 http://10.100.102.109:8090/feed1.ffm
```

this command works but,  the first output is audio , therefore my third app cant view this output 
this is my output:

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (pcm_s16le) -> amix:input0 (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (pcm_s16le) -> amix:input1 (graph 0)
  amix (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (aac)
  Stream #2:0 -> #0:1 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
-async is forwarded to lavfi similarly to -af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Output #0, ffm, to 'http://10.100.102.109:8090/feed1.ffm':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : now
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 aac
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (h264_nvenc) (Main), bgr0, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 1500 kb/s, 8 fps, 1000k tbn, 8 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 h264_nvenc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 1500000/0/1500000 buffer size: 3000000 vbv_delay: -1
```

****how can i replace the output that the video will be first?****

(when i do this command with 1 audio and 1 video inputs, the output is fine, the video is first , and the third part App can view it)

i spent a lot of hours on it please help me.

tnx a lot ...

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of mapping, output streams from complex filtergraphs will be ordered before other streams. So, add a label to the filter_complex output and map in the order required.

Use

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -async 1 \
-f pulse -i alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor \
-f pulse -i alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo \
-f x11grab -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 8 -i :0.0 \
-filter_complex "amix=inputs=2[a]" \
-map 2:v -map '[a]' \
-c:a aac -b:a 128k \
-c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 1500k -maxrate 1500k -minrate 1500k \
-override_ffserver -g 16 http://10.100.102.109:8090/feed1.ffm
```

Comment: just a little fine tuning,  the inputs are maped in this order:  first input = 0 , second input = 1, third input = 2 etc... so i changed in your command, the -map 0:v to -map 2:v because my video input is the third.....-map '[a]'  and all the rest stay as is